# Git yaml code not pulling/sending results to the database

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wrote a python script that pulls data from the database, runs these data through a classification model and sends the results back to the database. The python code already works on my VS code but I want to schedule it to run every day so I uploaded to Gitlab.

In my Gitlab project I have:

```
requirements.txt
predict.py
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml code looks like this:

```
image: python:latest

stages:
    - node1
  
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
  
before_script:
  - python -V # Print out python version for debugging
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

node1:
  stage: node1
  script:
  - python predict.py
  tags: [windows]
```

Gitlab gave no errors for the yml file so I went ahead to schedule the script using the CI/CD scheduler.

The problem is that it does not drop the expected files into the database and I suspect it's the yml file configuration.

Am I doing anything wrong or not enough?